# Only connections established with Active Directory... Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I am trying to enable Active Directory access for an Azure SQL Database. But I ran in a bit of a chicken-egg problem:

- On the properties tab of my SQL database, The Active Directory admin shows an AD user group I am a member of
- I cannot login. If I try to connect to my database using this AD-user, either via the Query editor (preview) tab or through SSMS, I get "**Login failed for user ''.**"
- If I login using the Server admin login or through a SQL account, I can login, but I cannot execute CREATE USER myname FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER. It returns "**Only connections established with Active Directory accounts can create other Active Directory users**"

How did I create this mess?

On Azure, I already had a SQL Server with a SQL database. I can login onto that server using my Active Directory account. I had a local database, and in SSMS I selected "Deploy database to Microsoft Azue SQL database..." and selected my existing SQL Server.

As I understand it, AAD needs to know the SQL server, not each individual SQL database. If I do a Point In Time restore of my main database, I can also access this database with my AAD-account. But of course, this database already contains the active directory user group.

So Azure thinks I can logon to the database with my AAD-account,
but the database itself does not know any AAD accounts.
And I can only create AAD accounts in the database when logged in with an AAD-account.

How do I create an Active Directory Account within my database without being logged on with an Active Directory Account?

Comment: Hi @realbart, If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do I create an Active Directory Account within my database without being logged on with an Active Directory Account?

No, we can't. In Azure SQL database, you need to first to configure the Azure AD admin for the SQL Server, then login the database with AAD admin account to create the AAD user.
[image]

I think you have configured it. As you said you can login with you AAD-account. That's the Azure AD admin account. It has the permission to access all the database.

**Important:**

- To create contained users mapped to Azure AD identities, **you must be
  logged in using an Azure AD account that is an administrator in the
  database in Azure SQL Database.** In SQL Managed Instance, a SQL login
  with sysadmin permissions can also create an Azure AD login or user.

Ref here: [Authorize database access to SQL Database, SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/logins-create-manage)